# How can I change the value of a field from a different class?

Tags: java

Here is a quote from my exercise:

> The method weight queried some information from the parameter object by calling its method. It is also possible to change the state of the parameter. Add to class Reformatory the method `public void feed(Person person)` that increases the weight of its parameter by one.

The problem is I cant think how to do this without using a constructor or extra parameters that were not given in the exercise template.

### Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reformatory theReformatory = new Reformatory();

        Person brian = new Person("Brian", 1, 110, 7);
        Person pekka = new Person("Pekka", 33, 176, 85);


        System.out.println(theReformatory.weight(brian));
        theReformatory.feed(brian);
        System.out.println(theReformatory.weight(brian));



    }
}
```

### Person

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int height;
    private int weight;

    public Person(String name, int age, int height, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

### Reformatory

```
public class Reformatory {

    private int weight;


    public int weight(Person person) {
        weight = person.getWeight();
        return weight;
    }

    public void feed(Person person) {
        weight++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to call the setter. Your variable `weight` in your `feed` method is local to that class. It has nothing to do with the other variable from`Person`. Java is pass by value, not reference. Variables are never linked together.

Comment: `Person` has a public `setWeight` method. Why not call that with a parameter that adds 1 to the result of `getWeight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way that you use `person.getWeight()` in the `weight(Person person)` method, you can use `getWeight` together with `setWeight`:

```
int newWeight = person.getWeight() + 1;
person.setWeight(newWeight);
```

You can of course also collapse this to a single line, if you want:

```
person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is *pass by value* and it is not possible to pass primitives by reference in Java. Therefore, in the Reformatory class you should get the Person's weight, increase it and set it again in Person object.

In Reformatory:

```
public void feed(Person person) {
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight()+1);
    }
```

Your solution increases the weight of the Reformatory object and not the Person's object.

Comment: Avoid questions in answers that need clarification (see [answer]). Could you also explain why this solves the issue and why OPs original approach does not work? That would increase the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare field `weight` in your `Reformatory`.

```
public class Reformatory {
    public int weight(Person person) {
        return person.getWeight();
    }

    public void feed(Person person) {
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight()+1);
    }
}
```